# Chrome does not install on windows xp sp3

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

I've been having a lot of difficulties installing Chrome on my desktop, I have Windows XP with SP3.
The setup program starts and then exits within a second. I can see in Process Viewer that it's accessing a lot of files and registry keys before exiting

Comment: Just check the event viewer for more details. If you get any info post it.

Answer (score 2):

The thread [Can't install Chrome on Windows XP SP3](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4990a91d031c5c4c&hl=en) discusses this problem.

First, ensure that you have the latest [XP SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=5B33B5A8-5E76-401F-BE08-1E1555D4F3D4&displaylang=en), rather than a release-candidate (RC).

Then, download Chrome setup, reboot in Safe mode and install.
(If it is already installed, uninstall first in Safe mode.)

If this doesn't work, you could follow the other rather convoluted directions in the above link.

Comment: unfortunately I can't start in safe-mode. And I can't install or change the SP3 setup... any other way?

Comment: Uninstall Chrome and try to use the links from the last entry in the above thread using Firefox (not IE). I hope that your account is administrator.