# How can I install Google Chrome on my Windows XP computer?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, installation

I can download Google Chrome from web page, but I can't install it. Every time it shows the message "please wait , installation in running". After this message I can't do anything on the Internet without restarting my PC. I need your advice.

Comment: You'll need Service Pack 3 installed if you don't have it already. Also, see this question: [Chrome does not install on windows xp sp3](http://superuser.com/questions/254384/chrome-does-not-install-on-windows-xp-sp3)

Comment: What does it mean "I can do nothing in internet"? Other browsers stop working? How are you connected to the internet? (through modem, router?)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the .exe file and get the new downloaded. Then you can try to install it. Make sure to connect with the internet.